# Merge Request: Adwords to Google-Adwords

Tags: bug, status-completed

Could we merge either `adwords` to `google-adwords` or `google-adwords` to `adwords`?

It seems pointless to have both of them, there is currently 36 questions tagged as `adwords` and 11 tagged as `google-adwords`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created this synonym: Adwords -> Google Adwords